# Make an imageView in triangular shape and onclickListener

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: Layout of my question]

I am trying to make a layout which looks like the image here. The images are triangular(yellow and purple triangle are images) and are in imageView whose boundaries are marked in black.

The desired layout is achieved but when implementing onClickListener on these images because of overlap of imageviews when i click on purple portion on right side, under the yellow triangle, instead of purple onclickListener the yellow one is executed.

Any help or ideas on how to wrap the boundaries of imageView to the shape of image would be helpful.

Comment: did u try setontouch listener ?

Comment: That is because your image size, try this library for triangle images 

[link](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview)

then try to implement onclicklistener.

Comment: I am talking about onClick so yes I have tried it.

Comment: @RvLalwani This library masks the images only but doesnt solve the problem

Comment: you can try this custom image view 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626199/how-to-define-a-triangle-layout-like-this-image-in-android)

in which bounds of your imageview will be fixed.

hope it will help.

Comment: @RvLalwani Thank you for the link and help. But it is not solving the problem !