# Set Click to two different triangular images in a single layout

Tags: android, layout

I tried to set click to the triangular images placed as shown in figure. But the problem is only one image click is working. And I have implemented as follows:

[image]

```
 <ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/twoWheeler" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:src="@drawable/front_screen_design_twowheeler" 
  android:scaleType="fitStart"/>


   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/fourWheeler" 
    android:src="@drawable/front_screen_design_fourwheeler" 
    android:scaleType="fitEnd" />



two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,BikeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FourActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is two and four, how did you initialise them?

Comment: I have initialized them as follows                                                             
  ImageView  two=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.twoWheeler); and                       
    ImageView four=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fourWheeler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your question I have created the same example for your solution.

I have used two images with half transparent area.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/triangle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/triangle2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView imageView, imageView1;
    private RelativeLayout rlParent;


    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        rlParent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlParent);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        rlParent.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(rlParent, this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageView:
                showToast("Image 1 Click");
                break;
            case R.id.imageView1:
                showToast("Image 2 Click");
                break;
        }
    }

    private class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        private ViewGroup viewGroup;
        private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

        public MyTouchListener(ViewGroup viewGroup, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
            this.viewGroup = viewGroup;
            this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    for (int pos = 0; pos < viewGroup.getChildCount(); pos++) {
                        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(pos);
                        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                        view.draw(canvas);
                        int x = (int) event.getX();
                        int y = (int) event.getY();

                        if (bitmap.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                            if (onClickListener != null) {
                                onClickListener.onClick(view);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

You can check below screenshots to check particular image click,

**Screenshots**

[image]
[image]

I hope it helps you.

Comment: can you tell what should be the image size

Comment: You can use any image size but the size of both images should be same. for example, I take both images of 600x600

Comment: @ Piyush Malaviya i got it Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The thing with imageview is it takes a rectangular space. So in your case one imageview is placed above another thus only one imageview is clicked. to achieve that you need to create custom class to implement triangular imageview click try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626199/how-to-define-a-triangle-layout-like-this-image-in-android) or look for custom [imageview](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview)...

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap them in a `FrameLayout`

```
framelayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //calculate the position by event.getX(),event.getY();
        if(point in triOne){

        }else{

        }
        return true;
    }
});
```